# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric al ejecutar sp

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cordial saludo.
Tengo la siguiente función con sus respectivos argumentos:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCombEquRevision2]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @consumo_real AS DECIMAL(10,1),
    @consumo_esperado AS DECIMAL(10,1),
    @horas_trabajadas AS DECIMAL(10,1),
    @maxPosibleHTrab AS DECIMAL(10,1),
    @percentilDifConsumo AS DECIMAL(10,1),
    @operacion AS VARCHAR(50)
```

Aplico la función dentro de un sp, recibiendo los argumentos de una tabla.
He podido identificar cual es el registro de la tabla y específicamente, el argumento que me genera el error, el cual esta relacionado con el parámetro @consumo_esperado.
El argumento que obtengo para dicho parámetro y que genera el error es:
@consumo_esperado = -1469645

Como lo pueden notar, aparentemente, el dato cumple con el tipo de dato exigido por la función para este parámetro (DECIMAL(10,1)).
El dato -146945 fue calculado en el sp en tablas temporales anteriores por medio de la multiplicación de los siguientes números:
-13735 * 107

El dato 107 es calculado dentro del sp en tablas temporales anteriores, sacando un dato promedio y el dato -13735 es calculado también de tablas temporales anteriores aplicando la función SUM().

En primer lugar, pensé que por utilizar tablas temporales, el tipo de dato que recibe la función estaba llegando con una precisión mayor a la definida y por ello convertí los datos en el sp antes de ejecutar dicha función así:

```
dbo.fnCombEquRevision2
(
    TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),a.consumo_real),
    TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),a.consumo_esperado),
    TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),a.horas_trabajadas),
    TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),a.maxPosibleHTrab),
    TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),a.percentilDifConsumo),
    a.operacion
)
AS solicitud,
```

A pesar de ello, el problema persiste, así que comencé a aumentar la precisión tanto en el en la función como en el sp hasta llegar a estos limites:
Función

```
@consumo_esperado AS DECIMAL(20,1),
```

sp

```
TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,1),a.consumo_esperado),
```

Pero aun así continua apareciendo el error.

Agradecemos sus recomendaciones.

Comment: Estás seguro, que es este `consumo_esperado` con -1469645 que produce el error? Aquí funciona: https://dbfiddle.uk/AZ29iIhR Quizás en vez es un dato demasiado largo de `operacion`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, creo que tampoco es operacion, ya que este es un tipo VARCHAR(50) y el campo contiene 'PRODUCCION'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo presente que estoy generando varias tablas temporales locales para poder llegar a mi fin, corregí el problema modificando el campo @consumo_esperado = -1469645, que se estaba generando al multiplicar -13735 * 107. El dato 107 estaba dentro de lo normal, pero el dato -13735 era ilógico, ya que normalmente no debe superar de 800. Luego de hacer esta corrección, todo funciono normalmente.